# SQL Server DTA Missing

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

Slightly OT, but...

I have two named instances of MSSQL 2008 Developer Edition and also SQL Express 2008 with Advanced Services.

I just went to use the DTA, and it is not anywhere on my system.

I went to setup to add it, and see that the checkbox for it is cleared (all others are checked), and it and every other shared tool is greyed out so I can't get it installed.

Before I uninstall all of this stuff, can anyone recommend a way to get this stuff installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the basic Management tools, or the complete set?

Comment: The only option for SQL Express is "Basic Management Tools", but I had installed the full boat of tools when I put Developer Edition on.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is "don't install SQL Server Express after you install Developer Edition".

I uninstalled all of the Shared Services (Basic Management Tools, etc) for the SQLExpress instance, then installed a new instance of Developer Edition, and I was able to then get the performance tools included. DTA is now back.